# can i edit url before redirect page?

Tags: php

can i edit url before redirect page  ?

first load page `test.php` and try to edit url before redirect page.

i try to edit url before redirect, but i can not do it ?

i want to know, Who can edit url before redirect page ?

test.php

```
<?PHP
header("Location: https://www.paypal.com/webscr?business=host@hostgator.com&cmd=_xclick&no_note=1&lc=US&currency_code=USD&bn=PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest&amount=200.50&item_name=play station&custom=EHMEMNVV@hotmail.com&item_number=1234444567890QWERTYUIO");
?>
```

Comment: The short answer is: yes

Comment: how to do ?   thank you'

Comment: Why is it so hard to edit a static URL? Just change it.

Comment: Alwin ------ but you can not see link url ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the URL into a variable or two like below then use the variables inside the redirect.  You can easily change the variables prior to the redirect.

```
header('location: ' . $https_url . $app_path . $app_name .'?e=1');
exit();
```